# C++ Inventory & Item Crafting System - turning "stuff" into hash_tag "garblygook" and reversing the hash_tags to get real "stuff"

Tags: c++, hash, tags

I'm creating a item crafting system for a game and need to be able to take any random selected items that a player could select and transform whatever items selected into a hash_tag which can then be compared to all the hash_tags from all item-mixes possible, searching for a correct match. This should be the simplest and fastest means to get the result I'm looking for, but of all other ways of doing this sort of thing (I've experience with just about all of them), hash tags are the one thing I've never even slightly touched. I've no idea where to even begin, and could use a lot of help with this.

Basically what it needs to do is allow the player to select anything he or she has, combine the selected things into a hash_tag and check the hash tag board for that number. Whether or not that number results in a "valid combination" or a "this is not a valid combination" doesn't matter, so long as all possible mixes are available on the hash tag board.

On the side there'll obviously be some code for picking things and removing them if there's a valid match and adding in the new item instead, but that's not what I need help with.
(Although anyone with suggestions on this I'll be glad to hear them!)

Comment: I've read this twice now and I still don't understand what your question is. Can you try to clarify your end need and/or add a specific hash-related question? Also, it won't take many source items before the "has tag board" will become prohibitively large.

Comment: I think you've been using Twitter too much. A hashtag is a *tag* introduced by the *hash character*, `#`. That's something completely different from a *hash*, which is used in data structures like *hash tables* for doing fast look-ups. They have nothing to do with tags. Are you sure the words you're using mean what you think they do? And what is this "board" you're talking about?

Comment: Are you looking for a reversible function that takes a list of items (Does their order matter?) to some small identifier and back? That wont be possible if you cannot make a few assumptions about your data.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Actually I don't use Twitter at all. As for board it's just a word I'm using, it has no meaning in this case. It could say "list," or it could say something else. The point I was trying to get across with that choice of wording was simply a location with all the possible hashes. I simply called it a board as I was seeing it as likely to become large enough to be too big visually to consider it a "list". My bad for causing confusion; but it was just a choice of descriptive wording.

Comment: @Mark & pmr: First, I did say I was completely new to the writing and usage of a hash for any purposes. But yes, what pmr suggested, is what I'm looking for help with. The question "does their order matter" does bring up a very good point that I hadn't considered. In some cases, order would result in a different hash.
Edit: Actually, order doesn't really matter. I can have the different resulting hashes simply be the "same thing."

Comment: I'm still lost about how you would go about determining if something is valid or not. Hardcoded?

Comment: @pmr: yep. totally hardcoded. As suggested by my teacher, I would NEED to have something already created to compare all attempted combinations. SO I don't mind if I hardcode that. Edit: Oh, and to answer something you asked that I should have answered earlier: Yeh, I can't expect the data passed in to be anything specific. It'd be comparing "whatever is inputted" turned into a hash of that data, against the list of hardcoded hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have gathered so far you have an ordered list of inputs
(the items being crafted) and are looking for a function that returns
a hash (probably for easy comparisons and storage) and also has the
property of being reversible.

Such a thing cannot exist for the general case as long as your hash
has less bits than your input data hashing will produce collisions and
with those collisions the backward transformation will be impossible.

A good start would be just to choose unique identifiers for each item
and use a list of those identifiers(order them by size if order is
irrelevant to the crafting) as the hash. Comparison will still be
reasonable fast.

Comment: Sounds about right. I'm glad my post didn't confuse you too much, as I am about as new as you can get to using hash.

Edit (cause I hit enter instead of shift-enter):
But what you describe is what I'm hoping to achieve. Could you describe for me how I go about doing that?